# How to destructure an array of objects while function passing in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I was trying to rewrite the todo app using functional Components and I could not figure out a way to destructure and array of objects. Appreciate any help.

The Original Component:

```
class ProductTable extends React.Component {
render() {
    let rows = [];
    let lastCategory = null;
    this.props.products.forEach(function(product) {
        if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
            rows.push(<ProductCategoryRow category={product.category} key={product.category} />);
        }
        rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.name} />);
        lastCategory = product.category;
    });
    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
        </table>
    );
  }
}
```

The Functional Component I am trying to write:

```
const ProductTable = ({products = []}) => {
let rows = [];
let lastCategory = null;

products.forEach(function (product) {
    if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
        rows.push(<ProductCategoryRow category={product.category} key={product.category} />);
    }
    rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.name} />);
    lastCategory = product.category;
});

return (
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

Can the FormalParameter be more restrictive?

```
const ProductTable = ({products = []}) => ...
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'restrictive'? And why not `ProductTable = (products = []) => ...`?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Here is a complete [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmRzKQ?editors=0010#anon-login).

Comment: You want something like `ProductTable = ({products = [{stocked, name, price}]})`? What do you expect to get then - an array `stocked`, another array `name` etc? Or an array `products` with objects that are stripped of all properties apart from those listed? Anyway, it is not possible. You could validate your input structure (I don't recommend that here) or use a statically typed language (e.g. typescript).

Comment: I wanted to document the fact that `products` is the formal parameter which is an array of product objects whose structure is  `{stocked, name, price}`.

Comment: Just add documentation comments: http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. Typescript might be the way to go. One thing I learned while going through React documentation is that refactoring to elevate state is a common thing, unless Redux is used. It would be much easier to refactor if there is type safety.